# RecyclerView add delimiter line

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My activity has a `RecyclerView`.  [Please see the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkE0F.jpg). 
The `RecyclerView` separate 2 parts. First part is the top view. Just show some value about the apps. Second part is the Calendar. I would like to add the line to check the bar is reached the target or not. Only second part has the delimiter line I try many ways but I can't add the line to the second part.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/history_norm_delimiter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/history_norm_delimiter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/history_norm_delimiter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/history_norm_delimiter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/history_norm_delimiter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/history_norm_delimiter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/history_norm_delimiter" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

The image view is the delimiter line. But it is not in `RecyclerView`. I would like to add it to `RecyclerView`.

Comment: add code that you have tried

Comment: I just try to put the line into layout. Not in the code

Comment: Then just paste you layout here please.

Comment: update code. Thanks

Comment: anybody can help me